# What recent research looks at how scientific theories are established?

Tags: reference-request, academic-history, theory

I'm interested in quantitative understanding of where new scientific theories come from, and the process by which they grow/develop/become established.  This is intended as mainly a sociological/practical question (what sequence of events leads to a new theory, and how can this be helped along) rather than as a philosophical or epistemological question.

It seems like one of the qualitative landmark works in that area is Thomas Kuhn's "The Structure of Scientific Revolutions".  Kuhn describes a sequence of finding anomalies, a crisis, and then (sometimes) a scientific revolution.

In contrast to qualitative inquiry, what **quantitative** research has been done in this field? (backed by at least some hard data)

Are there any particularly important articles/books that propose a quantitative model?

Comment: I feel like this is drifting awfully close to ["please do not ask questions about...the content of your research, rather than the process of doing research"](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @BenVoigt: It is about the process of doing research.  That's something I'm interested in, and I imagine is also of general interest.

Comment: The original title was awfully broad. Since you are interested in pointers to articles/books, I have edited the title to clarify (that you're looking for established research, not individual user's thoughts on the subject) and added the [tag:reference-request] tag.

Comment: This needs further editing. Last part (data mining) is very narrow, specific and at the same time remote to original question. There is also another fundamental issue: _quite old_ does not equal _obsolete_. You cannot dismiss Kuhn (or any other scholar) simply because you think their work is _old_.

Comment: @Parrhesiastes:  I don't dismiss Kuhn, I think he captured some very important aspects of the subject.  At the same time, he's approaching this as a philosopher, not as (eg) a sociologist or historian; so his work is very thin on facts.  Surely *someone* has done a more substantive followup since then?

Comment: This is an entirely different discussion: Kuhn was a [historian](http://news.mit.edu/1996/kuhn) of [science](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008761217221) (not a philosopher in his own words too) and his work has influenced the contemporary [sociology](http://www.jstor.org/stable/589851) of [science](http://www.jstor.org/stable/589735). Second, an approach is thin on facts because it's philosophical is flawed argument. Perhaps you can either read more Kuhn or exclude him and be more specific in what you are looking for.

Comment: Further to my last comment, the question of "how theories are established" is a philosophical question (yet you are not interested in it). Philosophy of Science (as well as of Mathematics) has a long history dealing with it. Also, Kuhn was not a quantitative scholar so it is best to exclude as the mid-part of question misleads. Are you after a quantitative data driven taxonomy to understand the development of scientific theories, if that is so, it should be said clearly.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well, in this case, the process of doing research sort-of **is** the content of the research in question. In my opinion / understanding, the point of that sentence is to exclude questions whose *only* relation to academia is the fact that the question asks about the content of a subject that is academic (e.g., physics, mathematics, etc.). In this case, there is an aditional connection, namely the subject being the sociology of academians.

Comment: This might be more on-topic in history of science...

Answer (score 3):

While it is not terribly much more recent than Kuhn, I highly recommend reading "Laboratory Life" by Latour and Woolgar, published in 1979.  This book attempts to take both an anthropological and a quantitative approach to the question of how scientific theories are established, and was produced following field-work where one of the authors worked as a technician in a major biological laboratory.

Whereas many philosophers of science such as Kuhn and Popper approach science from a very high-level view, this book instead asks the question of what it is that scientists actually do all day, and why.  It views progress in science in terms of micro-scale arguments about the soundness of assertions, and presents several case studies of investigations and investigators, quantifying them with bibliometrics.

I will warn that the presentation includes a heavy dash of post-modernist thought and language that will turn some people off from the work.  Personally, I find it to not be particularly problematic---just take certain assertions with a grain of salt, just as you would any other investigative work.